# Countif does not work with hours and/ or dates

Tags: excel, countif

Hi I have data inside 3 columns:

A. Destination (es. LosAngeles)
B. Carrier      (es. Ups)
C. Shipment Time (es. 4:00)

The time used is the 24h time without Am/Pm

I need to do a countif  to know how many shipments we have at a specific time.

Tried with:
=COUNTIF(A1:A100,">="&TIME(8,30,0))-COUNTIF(A1:A100,">"&TIME(9,0,0)
Result 0

Tried with:
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,">=8:30",A1:A100,"<=9:00")
Result 0

Tried with:
=COUNTIF('sheet1'!I:I,"<="&TIME(4, 0, 0))
Result 0

Any help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: MOst likely your times are either text that looks like time or the time includes date information and not just time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,">="&TIME(8,30,0),A1:A100,"<="&TIME(9,0,0))
```

The formula below was missing a closing bracket at the end

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100,">="&TIME(8,30,0))-COUNTIF(A1:A100,">"&TIME(9,0,0))
```

Comment: Could you please give my answer a tick. It helps my rating and to also close this question. Glad I could help mate.