# Implementing HOUR with COUNTIFS

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

`Table` sheet tabulates data from the `Data` tab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YUTnJ_2xM6115gUV1MCReMR93k-8LuVupJ1ObdbuI0U/edit?usp=sharing

The breakdown is based on the `Data` tab, `Col B` and `Col E`.

Currently I am using a helper column to determine the hour recorded in the `Date` column (`Col A`).

I would like to modify the `COUNTIF` formulae in the `Data` tab to eliminate the need for the helper column.  My current formulae is of the following format:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!$A$18:$A,">"&$A$7,Data!$C$18:$C,E$2,Data!$B$18:$B,$C3,Data!$E$18:$E,E$1)
```

I have tried using the `HOUR` function within the `COUNTIF` formula (refer `E3` on `Table` tab) but receive an error: "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size."

I've also tried to implement the concept from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229652/countif-does-not-work-with-hours-and-or-dates) question, however, I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(Data!$A$18:$A, ">"&$A$7, 
                       Data!$C$18:$C,  E$2, 
                  HOUR(Data!$B$18:$B), $C3, 
                       Data!$E$18:$E,  E$1))
```

tho if **Data!B18** is not in true hour format use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(Data!$A$18:$A, ">"&$A$7, 
                       Data!$C$18:$C,  E$2, 
                       Data!$B$18:$B,  $C3, 
                       Data!$E$18:$E,  E$1))
```